# Error while taking RDP in Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp, connectivity

I am getting the following error while taking RDP of the Amazon instance(Windows Server 2008 R2): 
"The task you are trying to do can't be completed because Remote Desktop Service is currently busy. Please try again in few minutes. Other users should still be able to log on.".

RDP is taken through restricted IP and no other user is logged in. The instance was launched in 2015 and RDP was accessible until it started producing error 5 days back.

Please let me know the cause and solution to this problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We'd like to provide answers, but your question does not contain much detail. Please Edit your question and provide more information --- For example, how did you create the Windows instance? Have you been able to connect to it in the past? How are you trying to connect to it (with what software)?

Comment: Which version of Windows is it running? Could it be [this known problem](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3014783/-remote-desktop-services-is-currently-busy-or-the-group-policy-client-failed-logon-error-when-you-log-on-to-an-application-in-windows-server-2008-r2?sd=rss&spid=14134#prerequisites)?